# $controller does not implement an isAuthorized() method in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have used Auth component in my OrdersController as follows:

```
 public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                        'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                    ),
                    'userModel' => 'Agent'
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'admins',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'deshboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => "You can't acces that page",
            'authorize' => 'Controller'
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        $this->Auth->allow('login','index');
    }
```

When I tried to login and username and password matched it redirect to adminc/deshboard with the following error message:

```
$controller does not implement an isAuthorized() method.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

I searched google for couple of hours no solution. What am I doing for this error? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Make sure debug mode is on and provide the more-specific error (as well as what version of CakePHP you're using).

Comment: cakephp version : v 0.2.9
And I enabled debug mode: Configure::write('debug', 2);

but no more specific error.

Comment: Have you implemented `isAuthorized()`?

Comment: I edited my code and used   if (!$this->isAuthorized()) {
            return $this->redirect(
                            array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'deshboard'));
        }
now it shows: Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred. my debug mode is 2

Comment: You're on cakephp 0.2.9???  Does that even exist?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: sorry version is: 2.6.7
I got this with echo Configure::version();
  exit;

@Dave

Comment: Where is your `isAuthorized()` function?

Comment: inside login() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `isAuthorized()`, like so:

```
class OrdersController extends Controller {
    //...

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        //auth check
        //return boolean
    }

    //...
}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html for more info.

Comment: public function isAuthorized($user) {
        print_r($user);
        exit;
    }
And inside login() function :
 $admin = $this->Admin->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('email' => $this->request->data['Admin']['email'], 'password' => $password)
            ));

            if ($this->isAuthorized($admin)) {
              // login succeeded
            } else {

            // login failed
            }
but this code does not print array of admin.

Comment: Okay. What's the problem?

Comment: I need the data of admins table to pass isAuthorised() function and check additional info. But $admin is empty. I checked my database entry. Even I want to show last query, nothing show nothing. :(

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and drop the `exit` statement (in case of any output buffering).